# Sympy vector addition returns sympy.core.add.Add instead of sympy.vector.vector.VectorAdd

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm trying to add vectors and then do a dot product. However, I can't do the product because the type of the added vector is wrong.

```py
a = N.x*2
b = N.y*2
vec = a + b
print("Vector type", type(vec))
```

Output: `Vector type <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>`

Expected output: `<class 'sympy.vector.vector.VectorAdd'>`

Comment: Can you post the full code including imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

N = CoordSys3D('N')
a = N.x * 2
b = N.y * 2
vec = a + b
print(type(N.x))
>>> <class 'sympy.vector.scalar.BaseScalar'>
```

The issue here is that `N.x` and `N.y` are scalar quantities and sympy doesn't register them as basis vectors. Instead of x, y and z as basis vectors sympy uses [i, j and k](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/intro.html#vectors-and-scalars).
So you just need to replace `x` with `i`, `y` with `j` and `z` with `k`.

```
    from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

    N = CoordSys3D('N')

    print(type(N.i))
    >>> <class 'sympy.vector.scalar.BaseVector'>
    print(type(N.j))
    >>> <class 'sympy.vector.scalar.BaseVector'>
    print(type(N.k))
    >>> <class 'sympy.vector.scalar.BaseVector'>

    vec = N.i * 2 + N.j * 2
    print(type(vec))
    >>> <class 'sympy.vector.vector.VectorAdd'>
```